# How do I make a "security environment"?

Tags: java, security

I need to do something I don't even know if is possible..

We have a code that handle crypted data, and we have another software that is open source and need to manipulate this data, both are desktop stand alone softwares.

I'm wondering, is there a way to create a "secure environment" in Java to use the open source software as a plugin, restricting this software's access do external world (I don't want it to externalize my decrypted data)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Maxim Z: My guess is: bad experience. The OP last question was stated as a fact (and a wrong fact wrong to boot), it got down-voted and closed. IMO he is trying to be cautious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the details, but a [Security Manager](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) is intended for that purpose, also a custom [ClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) might prevent loading of resources you don't want to get loaded.